# How to access and use Tizen Device Manager using Command Line Interface

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I want to acces Tizen Device Manager and switch the connection on/off using CLI, is it possible to do so ?
This is how GUI for Tizen Device Manager looks like ?
[Device Manager GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED8BC.png)

In this I can switch the button on/off to enable or disable the connection.

I want to achieve the same using the CLI and not from the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate the Tizen Device Manager to connect your remote Device so that you can install and run your application on the remote samsung device as target without actually using Device Manager GUI, all you can do is use Samsung Development Bridge (SDB), if SDB is available on your system then open the terminal and execute the following command -

```
sdb connect <ip-address>:<port>
```

If the remote device is available on the network it will be connected

If you dont have SDB available on your system then you can find it in this -
https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2019/01/16/install-tizen-baseline-sdk

Now, if you want install or run the application on the remote device may be a TV then you can execute these commands using tizen CLI -

Installing the Application :

`tizen install <package file name>`

Running the Application :

`tizen run -p <appId>`

Make sure to execute above two commands, you must have tizen cli available on your system.
For more tizen cli commands visit -  https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli